# Raspberry Pi GPRS Connection: Unable to browse after ppp connection is established

Tags: raspberry-pi, uart, gprs, ppp, sim900

I have a persistent problem browsing after connecting my GPRS/GSM Module to Raspberry Pi.
I bought the GSM/GPRS Module on amazon at [http://www.amazon.com/SainSmart-Small-GPRS-SIM900-Arduino/dp/B00TEUAJMQ/ref=pd_sim_147_4?ie=UTF8&dpID=517DbMGK%2B9L&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_&refRID=17HH346MFMXS37D4TX8H](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00TEUAJMQ).

I have followed the instructions as given on this site

https://learn.adafruit.com/fona-tethering-to-raspberry-pi-or-beaglebone-black?view=all

The results were as expected. I obtained the local and remote IP address needed, i got the DNS addresses too.

Running "ifconfig", i have the result below which clearly shows i can communicate via ppp0.

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:21.144.145.193  P-t-P:10.64.64.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:72 (72.0 B)  TX bytes:111 (111.0 B)
```

The problem now is that i cannot successfully ping any IP address. I keep getting "Networking not reachable" or "unknown host" in case of a url.

More so, the LED light that shows the connection is meant to be blinked twice each second but stops blinking after ppp connection in established.

Please if anyone has a suggestion on what might possibly be causing this, help me out!

Comment: This question is more likely to get good answers on [Raspberry Pi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), where the real experts hang out ;)

Comment: Alright, thanks @Hexaholic